# How do we draw a diagram of a circle shaped thing with four arrows pointing up, down, left, and right?

Tags: diagrams, arrays, technical-drawing

I was wanting to draw something like the following:

[image: a screen capture of five circles. one circle in the middle. one circle to the west. one circle to the east. one circle to the north. one circle to the south. five circles total]

The motivation was to illustrate a data-structure some people refer to as a "***two-dimensional linked list***"

```
class TwoDeeNode {

    // NODE HAS FOUR MEMBER VARIABLES  

    Pointer<TwoDeeNode> left;
    Pointer<TwoDeeNode> right;
    Pointer<TwoDeeNode> up;
    Pointer<TwoDeeNode> down; 
}
```

However, the **LaTeX** code got to be almost unreadable, and I am stuck now.

Eventually, I might or might not write a compiler which compiles something human-readable for the diagrams into **LaTeX** code for the diagrams.

However, we type up some simple examples in **LaTeX**?

I was going to use an array with five center-justified columns.

```
\begin{array}{ccccc}
...
\end{array}
```

As usual, the ampersands `&` act as column separators in the source code.

```latex
\require{enclose} 

\usepackage{graphicx}   

\begin{array}{ccccc}   
\text{} & \text{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{x.up}} & \text{} & \text{}   \\\\
\text{} &  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\\\
\Large{\enclose{circle}{x.left}} & \xleftarrow{left} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{x}} & \xrightarrow{right} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{x.right}}   \\\\
\text{} &  \text{ } & \scriptsize{down}\large{\downarrow} & \large{\downarrow} \\\\  
\text{} & \text{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{x.down}} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &    \\\\ 
\end{array}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)  circle(.2) node {$x$};
        \draw (3,0)  ellipse(.8 and .2) node {$x.right$};
        \draw (-3,0)  ellipse(.8 and .2) node {$x.left$};
        \draw (0,1.5)  ellipse(.8 and .2) node {$x.up$};
        \draw (0,-1.5)  ellipse(.8 and .2) node {$x.down$};
        \draw[-latex] (.8,0)--(1.5,0) node[midway,yshift=.15cm] {\tiny $right$};
        \draw[-latex] (-.8,0)--(-1.5,0) node[midway,yshift=.15cm] {\tiny $left$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,.5)--(0,1) node[midway,right] {\tiny $up$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-.5)--(0,-1) node[midway,left] {\tiny $down$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```